# Python imports across modules and global variables

Tags: python, import, python-module

I have a question which seems to be rather fundamental but I can't seem to find any help on this anywhere.

```
file_a.py >>

from xyz import XYZ
class A:
    .
    .
    .

file_b.py >>

import file_a
from file_a import A
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)

    def someMethod(self):
        XYZ.doSomething()
```

XYZ.doSomething() fails saying NameError: name 'XYZ' is not defined
Even standard imports like 'import sys' done from file_a does not seem to render it usable in file_b. I assumed that should work. Is my understanding wrong? If yes, then is there a way to have common imports and global variables across files? (If it is of nay help, I've been a C++ and java programmer and am now starting to use python. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is my understanding wrong?

Yes, because the line `from file_a import A` import only class `A` into the namespace of `file_b`. The namespace of `file_a` is left alone. If it were not like this, there would be little sense in having both syntax:

```
import modulename
from modulename import something
```

as if your thinking was right, then after the second form you would always be able to use `modulename.someotherthing`.

> If yes, then is there a way to have common imports and global variables across files?

Yes, with the star `*` operator:

```
from modulename import *
```

but this brings the issue of namespace pollution, for example `from file_a import *` will import in `file_b` also all the imports done in `file_a`. You *will* eventually lose control of your imports and this will bite you at some time... trust me on this!

When for some reason `from module import *` is needed, a workaround to namespace pollution is to define in `module` the [variable `__all__`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package), which whitelists what should be imported with the star operator.

HTH!

Answer (score 4):

When you import a module, all the variables defined in that module are available in its namespace. Hence, if `XYZ` is available in `file_a` module, when you `import file_a` you can access `XYZ` as `file_a.XYZ`.

The general idea here is that your namespace shouldn't be cluttered with the contents of other namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your understanding is wrong. Each module is its own namespace, and only things you explicitly import within that file are available in that namespace.

Contrary to other answers, it is not particularly Pythonic to refer to `file_a.XYZ`, although this will work. Instead, you should import XYZ and sys at the top of `file_b`.

Comment: Well that's my question. I want to avoid repeating a set of imports across many files like file_b. I know that importing XYZ and sys into file_b works.

Comment: @ksrini You shouldn't want that. It is good to explicitly import everything a module uses. It neatly lists all dependencies in one place. See PEP20 - explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Thank you yak, that was interesting and insightful!

Answer (score 1):

```
import file_a
from file_a import A
```

I think the problem is: you do not import XYZ really!

```
from fila_a import *
```

can solve your problem,but it is not a good way~~~

you can write this in file_b:

```
from file_a import XYZ
```

It is done?