# Automatically import to all Python files in the given folder?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, python-module

*I am relatively quite new to Python and I try to learn the "Pythonic" way of doing things to build a solid foundation in terms of Python development. Perhaps what I want to achieve is not Python at all, but I am nonetheless seeking to find out the "right" way to solve this issue.*

I am building an application, for which I am creating modules. I just noticed that a module of mine has 7 different .py Python files, all importing 3 different same things. So all these files share these imports.

I tried removing them, and inserting these import to the empty **init**.py in the folder, but it did not do the trick.

If possible, since these imports are needed by all these module files, I would not like them to be imported in each file one by one.

What can I do to perform the common import?

Thank you very much, I really appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Imports are cheap. Importing the same module in multiple locations is not going to be a problem.

Comment: I think you should not use a common import and instead explicitly import dependencies in each file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) states, "Explicit is better than implicit", and this is a good example.

It's very useful to have the dependencies of a module listed explicitly in the imports and it means that every symbol in a file can be traced to its origin with a simple text search. E.g. if you search for `some_identifier` in your file, you'll either find a definition in the file, or `from some_module import some_identifier`. It's even more obvious with direct references to `some_module.some_identifier`. (This is also one reason why you should not do `from module import *`.)

One thing you could do, without losing the above property, is to import your three shared modules into a fourth module:

```
#fourth.py
import first
import second
import third
```

then...

```
#another.py
import fourth

fourth.first.some_function()
#etc.
```

If you can't stomach that (it does make calls more verbose, after all) then the duplication of three imports is fine, really.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with DrewV, it is perfectly pythonic to do

File1:

```
import xyz

import abc
```

...

File2:

```
import xyz
```

An almost identical question has also been addressed in the following link:

[python multiple imports for a common module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689252/python-multiple-imports-for-a-common-module)

As it explains, Python does the job of optimising the module load, so you can write multiple import statements and not worry about performance losses, because the module is only *loaded* once. In fact, listing out all the imports in each file makes it explicitly clear what each file depends on.

And for a discussion of how imports interact with namespaces, see:

[Python imports across modules and global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165703/python-imports-across-modules-and-global-variables)